# Is that safe to restart postgresql server while vacuum full running? Or kill the vacuumdb processes?

Tags: postgresql

I got my vacuumdb running, but accidentally i start it multiple times with statement_timeout = 0 parameter, so im afraid that this can take to much time to complete.

My question is, can i safely kill the process of theese vacuum or just restart server while its running?

```
xxx=# select pid, backend_start, query_start, state_change, state, query from pg_stat_activity where application_name = 'vacuumdb' OR query like '%reload%';


pid  |         backend_start         |          query_start          |         state_change          | state  |                                                                         query                                                                          
-------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1273 | 2017-03-25 13:18:48.355737+03 | 2017-03-25 13:18:56.318492+03 | 2017-03-25 13:18:56.319311+03 | idle   | select pg_reload_conf();
 32102 | 2017-03-25 13:14:26.737586+03 | 2017-03-25 13:14:26.74256+03  | 2017-03-25 13:14:26.742566+03 | active | VACUUM (FULL, VERBOSE, ANALYZE) xxx;                                                                                                  +
       |                               |                               |                               |        | 
  2693 | 2017-03-25 13:22:44.275979+03 | 2017-03-25 13:46:48.168615+03 | 2017-03-25 13:46:48.168625+03 | active | select pid, backend_start, query_start, state_change, state, query from pg_stat_activity where application_name = 'vacuumdb' OR query like '%reload%';
 31746 | 2017-03-25 13:13:07.173855+03 | 2017-03-25 13:13:07.178614+03 | 2017-03-25 13:13:07.178621+03 | active | VACUUM (FULL, VERBOSE, ANALYZE) xxx;                                                                                                  +
       |                               |                               |                               |        | 
 16923 | 2017-03-25 12:28:31.537226+03 | 2017-03-25 12:28:31.543027+03 | 2017-03-25 12:28:31.543032+03 | active | VACUUM (FULL, VERBOSE, ANALYZE) xxx;                                                                                                  +
       |                               |                               |                               |        | 
(5 rows)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is 100% safe to just restart postgres with `vacuum` running. This is true for `VACUUM`, `VACUUM (FULL)`, `CLUSTER`, etc.

It won't even have to restart the work completely at the beginning, it can keep some of the work done before the restart.